# Warning on PHP fopen

Tags: php, fopen

```
$file = @fopen("http://ajax.htm","rb");
```

I am getting this error while using `fopen`

```
Warning: fopen(xyz.htm): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
in /home/user/public_html/aaa/ttt.php on line 8
```

what could be the reason behind this?

Comment: could you please post the complete statement? the statement that contains this fopen() function call, if you please.

Comment: i have edited my post u can check there

Comment: You already posted this question.  Just edit your previous one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887013/error-on-using-fopen/887038#887038

Answer (score 7):

I am going to go out on a huge limb here and suggest the problem is the url, 'http://ajax.htm'.

Answer (score 1):

[from docs](http://php.net/fopen):

> If PHP has decided that `filename`  specifies a registered protocol, and that protocol is registered as a network URL, PHP will check to make sure that [`allow_url_fopen`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled. If it is switched off, PHP will emit a warning and the fopen call will fail.

**edit**: `ajax.htm` is not a valid url.

Comment: allow_url_fopen is enabled here....i dont think that this error is because of allow_url_fopen coz this code of mine was not giving any error utill now but suddenly gave this error today.....

Comment: may be you could remove @ to see more?

Comment: i have fixed the problem.The original url that i was reading was having error and this code couldnt read that. :-)...thnx all for your help...

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = @fopen("ajax.htm","rb");
```

there is your problem i think

https://www.php.net/function.fopen

Comment: huh? "Note: For portability, it is strongly recommended that you always use the 'b' flag when opening files with fopen(). "

Comment: yes you are right....'b' is always strongly recommended and i dont think it gives any kinda error.